# JAVA two-dimensional array страны

Tags: java, массивы

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с задачей по JAVA и не могу с ней разобраться.
Есть такой массив:

```java
String[][] arr = {
        {"Kenya", "Nairobi"}, {"Rwanda", "Kigali"},
        {"Gambia", "Banjul"}, {"Ghana", "Accra"},
        {"Niger", "Niamey"}, {"Zambia", "Lusaka"}
};
```

Нужно, чтобы программа запрашивала название страны и выводила её столицу. Если данной страны не существует, то вывести соответствующее сообщение.

Comment: С чем конкретно вы не можете разобраться?

Comment: Как мне это сделать...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваши текущие наработки, иначе данная задача выглядит как учебная, а полностью решать такие задачи здесь не принято.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String getCapital(String[][] arr){
    for (String[] countryCapital: arr) {
        if (countryCapital[0].equals("Rwanda")){
            return countryCapital[1];
        }
    }
    return "no country";
}
```

input думаю понятно как сделать

Answer (score 0):

Можно из этого массива собрать карту:

```java
String[][] arr = {
        {"Kenya", "Nairobi"}, {"Rwanda", "Kigali"},
        {"Gambia", "Banjul"}, {"Ghana", "Accra"},
        {"Niger", "Niamey"}, {"Zambia", "Lusaka"}
};

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>() {
    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        return super.getOrDefault(key, "Такой страны не существует");
    }
};

map.putAll(Arrays.stream(arr)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(row -> row[0], row -> row[1])));

System.out.println(map.get("Kenya")); // Nairobi
System.out.println(map.get("Zambia")); // Lusaka
System.out.println(map.get("Лфв2ыло")); // Такой страны не существует
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String countryName = getCountryNameFromConsole;
for(String country : arr) {
   if (country.name is countryName)
       then return countryCapital;
}

return some errorMessage;
```

думаю алгоритм понятен